# modal function not showing the modal

Tags: javascript, php, html, modal-dialog

Hi im writing a function that i can reuse to show/hide modals and on my website 
but it does not seem to work. when i used the same code outside a funtion and using direct id and class names instead of variables it worked fine its only when im passing them in that it does not appear to work?

```
<input id="lrBtn" type="button" value="Login/Register" onclick="ShowModal('PopUpLR','closeLR');" />




function ShowModal(var popup,var closeBtn){
        var modal = document.getElementById(popup);
        var span = document.getElementsByClassName(closeBtn)[0];
        modal.style.display = "block";
        span.onclick = function() {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
        window.onclick = function(event) {
            if (event.target == modal) {
                modal.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you got Bootstrap + JQuery loaded?

Comment: Also, you could try moving the code above the button?

Comment: tried code above button still nothin :( i have jquery loaded but not bootstrap as im not using it atm should i?

Comment: I'm not as experienced in HTML nor JavaScript, but I think that Models are a Bootstrap only thing, not sure though.

Comment: The way you define function is wrong you should write your ShowModal(popup,closeBtn) insted of ShowModal(var popup,var closeBtn)

Comment: @user3273700 put that as an answer please it worked :P too much c# today :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you define your ShowModal function is wrong You need to write it like this

```
function ShowModal(popup,closeBtn){
 // your code
}
```

instead of

```
function ShowModal(var popup,var closeBtn)
{
// your code
}
```

Full code:

```
function ShowModal(popup,closeBtn){
        var modal = document.getElementById(popup);
        var span = document.getElementsByClassName(closeBtn)[0];
        modal.style.display = "block";
        span.onclick = function() {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
        window.onclick = function(event) {
            if (event.target == modal) {
                modal.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
```